# Search and replace a single cell in a specific column with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen pretty much similar apps yet am having difficulty doing it.

COL Name

1
 2
 3
  4

I need to switch two numbers for e.g. So if i set 1 as 3 then the 3 gotta change to 3 auto. It happens only in col 2.

```
function
switch (trid, newnumber, oldnumber) {
  //change any existing numbers first i.e. do the switch

  $("tbody#tbody tr").each(function() {

        if ($(this).find("td").eq(0).text() == newnumber) {
          //problem pure repetition here. How do i just replace the cell been compared?
          $(this).find("td").eq(0).text(oldnumber)
        }

        $('#' + trid + ' td').eq(1).html(newnumber);
      }
```

The above code does work but it is not the right away obviously. I tried capturing $(this).index but that is index of the tr instead of the specific td.

The structure of the table is just tbody tr td

any input?

Comment: Could you post valid js code please?

Comment: make a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: save `$(this).find("td").eq(0)` in a variable and re use it for compare and set value